# regex - how to make it accept arabic & english alpha

Tags: php, javascript, regex

I have this regex

```
'/^[-a-zàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöøùúûüý€0-9\s*\.\'\/",_()|& ]*$/i'
```

It does not accept arabic chars.
How can i do this?

Or how can I edit it to not accept `* & ^ % $` and all non alpha english & arabic chars?

This regex in
http://code.google.com/p/validformbuilder/

Answer (score 0):

Use XRegExp with Unicode Base Addon:

http://xregexp.com/plugins/

Answer (score 0):

You should check if it works for all your test cases, but as far as I can tell, the Arabic script is found in Unicode code points `0x0621` through `0x06FF`,  `0xFB50` through `0xFDFB`, and `0xFE70` through `0xFEFC`, so if you don't want to use `XRegExp`, you can try (JavaScript)

```
var myregexp = /^[\wàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöøùúûüý€\s*.'\/",()|& \u0621-\u06FF\uFB50-\uFDFB\uFE70-\uFEFC-]*$/i;
```

or (PHP)

```
regex = '%^[\wàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöøùúûüý€\s*.\'/",()|& \x{0621}-\x{06FF}\x{FB50}-\x{FDFB}\x{FE70}-\x{FEFC}-]*$%iu'
```